# Number of PMP, CSM and Prince2-certified PMs

Tags: scrum, pmp, prince2, certification

What are current world-wide numbers of people who are:

- PMP (Project Management Professional)
- CSM (Certified Scrum Master)
- Prince2 certified

Answer (score 5):

For **Prince2** there was a study saying following:

> In the past few years, certification has had a steady growth of approximately 25% per year. This trend is expected
>   to continue for at least a couple of years.
>   The following graph shows the PMI and IPMA certifications. Unfortunately, there are no statistics about the total
>   number of PRINCE2 certified people worldwide since 2000.
>   However estimates are that in 2009, more than half a million people have a PRINCE2 certification.

http://www.sts.ch/documents/english/pm_certif.pdf

in 2008 Total (World) 
foundation: 79,885 
practitioner: 41,791

**Project Management Professional (PMP)**

> As of 31 July 2010 (2010 -07-31),
>   there were 393,413 active PMP
>   certified individuals worldwide.  Over
>   4,300 individuals a month, since
>   September 2006, have obtained a PMP
>   certification

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Management_Professional

Answer (score 1):

#### Certified ScrumMaster (CSM)

Actual numbers are now available on the Scrum Alliance web site. [As of November 21, 2013 there are nearly a quarter million CSMs (249,221).](http://www.scrumalliance.org/scrum/media/ScrumAllianceMedia/Files%20and%20PDFs/Why%20Scrum/Class-Certification-Stats-Oct-2013.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

### Project Management Professionals (PMP)

The PMI publishes their membership and credential stats periodically. The latest numbers I could find were from their February 2014 *PMI Today* publication. The numbers are as of 31 December 2013:

- Certified Associate in Project Management (CAPM): 24,450
- Project Management Professional (PMP): 594,603

There are a number of specialization certifications, but they are all still under 5,000 recipients.

I'd place a link to this resource, but it is available online only to members. The reference is: PMI Today, February 2014, Pg. 4, PMI Fact File.

Polymath (PMP, PMI-ACP)